# About Contacts API Deprecation Details

Tags: oauth-2.0, contacts, google-contacts-api, google-shared-contacts

As contacts api version 2 is deprecated. I am using contact api version 3. 
I am not getting, whether any method from below code is deprecated or not. I am confused there. Please guide me here.

```
        ContactsService contactService = new ContactsService("Application Name");
        contactService.setAuthSubToken(custDetails.getGoogleCredentionals().getAccessToken());
        try {
            String url="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/"+domain+"/full/"+contactId;
            entry = contactService.getEntry(new URL(url),ContactEntry.class);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            log.warning("exception in create entry obj"+e1);
        }
```

Comment: Deprecation of what methods are you looking for? Check this page for all the possible methods you can do in Contacts API v3: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#creating_a_google_account

Comment: I am also using Google Data APIs Client Library version 1.47.1 jar. I want to know whether, Google Data Api  Client Library is deprecated or only some classes within are deprecated.